# I forgot to add attributes on my references so it will generate a foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have class DeviseCreateUsers, CreateCategories and CreateTasks < Active::Migration

Under CreateTasks

```rb
    class CreateTasks < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
      def change
      create_table :tasks do |t|
      t.string :taskname
      t.text :taskbody
      t.string :time
      t.references :category   -----> I forgot to add null: false, foreign_key:true
      t.timestamps
      end
    end
    end
```

Now Im trying to create a new task

```rb
     def create
      @categories = Category.find(params[:category_id])
      @tasks = @categories.tasks.create(category_params)
      if @tasks.save
      redirect_to category_tasks_path
      else
      render :new
      end
    end

    def category_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:taskname,:taskbody,:time)
    end
```

It's not saving the task. I'm thinking if `null: false, foreign_key:true` that I forgot to add has something to do about this.

I tried to byebug on the `task#create`:

```rb
    @categories = Category.find(params[:category_id])

    @tasks = @categories.tasks.create(category_params)
```

The params are there but the task id is nil.

if `null: false, foreign_key:true` has something to do about this, how can I update the attribute for just the task so i can reference it to category?

I see rails migration .... but I'm not sure if I will be able to do it just for the task.

Comment: Do your model classes include the associations?

Comment: yes . in user.rb i have has_many:categories has_many_:tasks
in category.rb i have belongs_ to :user has_many :tasks
in task.rb i have belongs_to :user belongs_to :category

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Use `create!` instead of just `create` to check if record is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the full picture, as you haven't shared your Task model. Do you have any validations there? Also, I don't think it's good practice to try to create a task via the category. What I think you should try to run on console is the following and see the outcomes:

```
# changed name as you are finding a single category
@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])

# initiate a new task first:
@task = Task.new(category: @category)
if @task.valid?
  @task.save
else
  @task.errors
end
```

This should either save, or tell you why the validation has failed.

Answer (score 0):

As I see from you log, I think user is missing in you migration, please rollback then add `t.references :user` to `CreateTasks` migration, then migrate again. I think the error will disappear.